# php mysqli login - after login the titlebar does not change according to the userlevel

Tags: php, session, authentication, mysqli

Hi all i am a newbie in php. I have made a login script which does not show any error when the page loads. It logs in and redirects to the profile page and but the titlebar does not change according to userlevel I checked made changes based on tutorials i watched but there is no success.

Here is my code.

Connection to database:

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);
session_start();?>
<?php
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'tl');
if($con->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Sorry, We\'re experiencing some connection problems.');
}
?>
```

Functions:

```
<?php
    function loggedin(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
?>
```

Titlebar:

```
    <div>
    <?php
        if(loggedin()==true){
            $user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];
            $log=$con->prepare("SELECT username,user_level FROM users WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
            $log->execute;
            $log->bind_result($username, $user_level,$user_id);
            $log->store_result;
            if($log->fetch()) //fetching the contents of the row
            {
                if($user_level=='a'){?>
                    <a href = 'index.php'>Home</a>
                    <a href = 'profile.php'>Profile</a>
                    <a href = 'admin.php'>Admin</a>
                    <a href = 'index.php'>Log Out</a>
                <?php
                }if($user_level=='m'){?>
                    <a href = 'index.php'>Home</a>
                    <a href = 'profile.php'>Profile</a>
                    <a href = 'index.php'>Log Out</a>
                <?php
                }
            }?>
        <?php
        }?><a href = 'index.php'>Home</a>
                    <a href = 'login.php'>Login</a>
                    <a href = 'register.php'>Register</a>
        <?php}
    ?>

</div>
```

Index Page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>LOGIN</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include 'connect.php';?>
<?php include 'functions.php';?>
<?php include 'titlebar.php';?>
Index

</body>
</html>
```

Login Page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>LOGIN</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include 'connect.php';?>
<?php include 'functions.php';?>
<?php include 'titlebar.php';?>

<h3>LOGIN HERE:</h3>
<form action ="" method="post">

User Name:<br/>
<input type='text' name='username' />
<br/><br/>
Password:<br/>
<input type='password' name='password' />
<br/><br/>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='login'>
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);


    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT user_id, username, password, status FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $password, $status);
    $stmt->store_result();
    if($stmt->num_rows == 1)  //To check if the row exists
        {
            if($stmt->fetch()) //fetching the contents of the row
            {
               if ($status == 'd') {
                   echo "YOUR account has been DEACTIVATED.";
                   exit();
               } 
               if ($status == 'b') {
                   echo "YOUR account has been BANNED.";
                   exit();
               } 
               if ($status == 'n') {
                   echo "YOUR account has NOT YET BEEN ACTIVATED.";
                   exit();
               } 
               else {
                   $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
                   $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                   $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    header('Location: index.php');
                    exit();
               }
           }

    }
    else {
        echo "INVALID USERNAME/PASSWORD Combination!";
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
else 
{   

}
$con->close();

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Profile Page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PROFILE</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include 'connect.php';?>
<?php include 'functions.php';?>
<?php include 'titlebar.php';?>
PROFILE</br>
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
    echo "Welcome to the member's area, " . $_SESSION['username'] . "!";
} else {
    echo "Please log in first to see this page.";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Logout:

```
 <?php
 include 'connect.php';
 include 'functions.php';
 session_destroy();
 header('location: index.php');
 ?>
```

Is there any thing i should change to make this work. After logging in the title bar does not change to admin or member menu. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: `'session_start()';` should be `session_start();`

Comment: now this works but the title bar is not changing i will update my question with titlebar please check that also

Comment: I get these errors.                             Notice: Undefined property: mysqli_stmt::$execute in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\login\titlebar.php on line 6

         Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\login\titlebar.php on line 7

            Notice: Undefined property: mysqli_stmt::$store_result in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\login\titlebar.php on line 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Musa identified the first issue -

```
'session_start()';
```

should be

```
session_start(); // without quotes
```

---

Based off the `Notice`/`Warning` in your comment.
change -

```
$log=$con->prepare("SELECT username,user_level FROM users WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
$log->execute;
$log->bind_result($username, $user_level,$user_id);
$log->store_result;
```

to (note according to http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php#99159, `store_result()` needs to be before `bind_result()`) -

```
$log=$con->prepare("SELECT username,user_level, user_id FROM users WHERE user_id='$user_id'"); // have 3 bind_result, but query only had 2
$log->execute(); // missing ()
$log->store_result(); // missing ()
$log->bind_result($username, $user_level,$user_id); // have 3 bind_result, but query only had 2
```

also, since you are using `prepare()`, you should use a parameter marker in your sql statement ie. `:user_id`

```
$log=$con->prepare("SELECT username,user_level, user_id FROM users WHERE user_id=:user_id"); // have 3 bind_result, but query only had 2
$log->execute(array(:user_id=>$user_id)); // missing ()
$log->store_result(); // missing ()
$log->bind_result($username, $user_level,$user_id); // have 3 bind_result, but query only had 2
```

**EDIT**
to fix your menu issue. You are missing the `else{` before the last menu group

```
 } else { ?><a href = 'index.php'>Home</a>
   ^^^^^^
                <a href = 'login.php'>Login</a>
                <a href = 'register.php'>Register</a>
 <?php } // also put a space between the opening tag and the curly bracket.
```

Comment: Now i have these errors nothing changed.

Notice: Undefined property: mysqli_stmt::$store_result in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\login\titlebar.php on line 8

Comment: and i have all the menu content lined up like this Home Profile Admin Log Out Home Login Register

Comment: looking at the manual for `store_result()`, according to this post (http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php#99159), you have to call it before `bind_`

Comment: the menu is all lined up. like in the last comment. and the log out is not working

Comment: everything is perfect now thank you I have one more problem with menu

Comment: could the log out not be working be because you have it linked to index.php -`<a href = 'index.php'>Log Out</a>`, instead of logout.php - `<a href = 'logout.php'>Log Out</a>`

Comment: yes i changed it But the menu for register and login also appears after login

Comment: you said that `everything is perfect now`, so is the menu fixed, or do you still need help with that?

Comment: i need help after login it show the register login menu with the logged in menu. Like this Home Profile Logout Home Login register

Comment: see the **EDIT** in my answer. Missing the `else{`

Comment: Thank you for youe help Sean. I will find out that.

Comment: You are most likely missing a closing bracket `}` after the `Home Login Register` menu. My guess is this line just before the closing div - `<?php}`. Try adding a space - `<?php }`. You can also paste your code into http://phpfiddle.org/ You can then 'click' on each bracket to see the matching bracket and see where it is missing.

Comment: yes i corrected it and i have one more problem if i open the titlebar.php file in url it shows this error.  Fatal error: Call to undefined function loggedin() in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\login\titlebar.php on line 3. What is this???

Comment: If you call a user created function - ie. `if(loggedin()==true)`, it must be defined, or it will cause a `Fatal error`. Since your `loggedin()` function is in `functions.php`, and you do not include it in `titlebar.php` it will error if you load `titlebar.php` directly. In all your other files you include `functions.php` before `titlebar.php` so it works properly.

Comment: Oh thank you so much to clearing my doubts. And sorry for asking so many questions. I am learning it by myself, no one to help here.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from what @Sean said about missing **()**, I don't see why you have `session_start()` inside single quotes.  Try this:

```php
if ( !isset($_SESSION) ) session_start();
```

If for some reason the session has already been initiated and you call `session_start()` then it will generate a warning about a session already being started and the `session_start()` being ignored.  The warning might not bother you, but to eliminate it completely do the if statement above.

If you want to initiate sessions only for people who have logged in:

```php
// At the top of the pages.
if ( !isset($_SESSION) && isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]) ) session_start();

// After the if ( isset($_POST) ) on the login screen
if ( !isset($_SESSION) ) session_start();
```